# MySQL Left join AND second select for count

Tags: mysql, left-join, multiple-tables

I have the following tables:

**pages**:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| page_id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| type       | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_id  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title      | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| text       | longtext     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**custom**:

```
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| page_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| key     | varchar(255)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| value   | longtext         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Whit the following query I get all the entries from table **pages** where `type = 'questions'` and get the values from table **custom** where `key = 'votes'`.

The problem here is this. In table **pages** I want to count all the entries with `type = 'comments' AND parent_id = 'page_id'`

```
SELECT * FROM pages AS P  
LEFT JOIN custom AS C
    ON P.page_id = C.page_id AND  
        C.key = 'votes'
WHERE  
    P.type = 'questions'  
ORDER BY P.date DESC, C.value DESC
```

The problem is I have to inset somewhere `SELECT COUNT(*) AS posts_count FROM pages WHERE page_id = parent_id` and the value from **posts_count** must be available in the query, because I want to order the entries by the order of comments AND after that by the votes from table **custom**

Comment: Can you post some sample data and sample results? Your question isn't 100% clear.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could use a subquery for to get this result:

```
SELECT p1.page_id,
  p1.type,
  p1.parent_id,
  p1.title,
  p1.text,
  Coalesce(p2.TotalComments, 0) TotalComments,
  c.key,
  c.value
FROM pages AS P1
LEFT JOIN
(
  select count(*) TotalComments, parent_id
  from pages
  where type = 'comments'
  group by parent_id
) p2
  on p1.parent_id = p2.parent_id
LEFT JOIN custom AS C
  ON P1.page_id = C.page_id 
  AND C.key = 'votes'
WHERE P.type = 'questions'  
ORDER BY P1.date DESC, C.value DESC
```